# Hibernate 3.6.0 with Maven

Tags: hibernate, maven

I'm having issues upgrading a pom file from Hibernate 3.3.2 to 3.6.0. I can compile fine, the jar file is being pulled down, but I get the following error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` when running Surefire tests. This class is in the referenced JAR, so I'm not quite sure what's going on here unless the classpath maven is using is somehow referencing the wrong jar.  I did a purge of my local repository cache to no avail.

A snip of my pom is below. Any thoughts?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
  <id>JBoss</id>
  <name>JBoss repository</name>
  <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended purging my repository and redownloading everything and it worked.  Ugh, best kind of error...

Answer (score 1):

`NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that the class could not be instantiated. One possibility is that some of the required dependencies for hibnernate are missing.  [This thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1008210) discussed your problem and suggests solution as well.

Comment: I found this solution as well, but in the answer, it looks like their `mvn install` command works correctly, its only when they are trying to run the finished product outside of maven that they need to muck with the classpath. I also was under the impression that Maven would get all the required sub-dependencies for a POM

Comment: @spintheblack maven does not know anything about runtime dependencies